# How to add Summary Links WP in page Layout in SP2013 Standard?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, web-part, design-manager

I'm coming to an issue :

1. I want to create a page layout whith a Summary Links Webpart.
2. I went to the design Manager
3. I chose my layout
4. I get the Snippet Gallery
5. I get the Summary Links WP code
6. I Copied/Pasted it to my layout via Sharepoint Designer
7. *I checked the code : nothing says "only in display mode".*

When i go to a page using this layout, I can see the title of the WP. When i want to edit the page, and add links to the webpart, i can't : i only see the title of the page, but nothing more, nor the "add group" nor "add links" buttons. So i can't edit my WP and add Summary links...

And this is what i want : i want the users to add Links to this specific WP. I don't want them to always be forced to add the WP when they create a page.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Gaëlle

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same struggle. I have found a way to make it work via a site column. I created a new site column with the choice of **Summary Links data**. I added the site column to the content type I am using for my page layout.

This allowed me to add a working summary links snippet to the page. The snippet will show up under **Page Fields** instead of **Dynamic Content**